# mysql scheme for inherit places

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have to create a database to store places in this way:

```
countries: id, name
regions: id, name, countries_id
municipality: id, name, regions_id
```

The same database has other tables related with this places. The problem is that not always the municipality (the most concrete location value) is known, some times we only know the region or the country. So we have to create the rest of the tables like this:

```
user: id, name, municipality_id, regions_id, countries_id
```

This scheme have problems due the duplications in the relationship. An user can be related with a region and a country, but this region is related also with a country.

What is the best way to handle with this problem? A possible solution would be something like this:

user: id, name, place_table, place_id

But this method does not allow to use foreing keys, and it's a bit harder to make queries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to store three fields in the `user` table.  This introduces a problem of consistency.

One solution is to keep your current table structure and extend the municipality table to include regions and countries.  So, each region and each country would be in the table.  The "country" municipality (say for France) would refer to the "France" region and that, in turn, to the "France" country.

My preferred solution would be to just have one table.  This denormalizes the structure.  However, the assumption is that this hierarchy does not really change very much (if at all).  Instead of the three tables, have a table called something like `Places`, with columns like `id`, `name`, `type`, `municipality_name`, `region_name`, `country_name`.

I realize this goes "against the grain" of normalized databases (although it corresponds to a dimension in dimensional analysis).  Assuming the values don't change, denormalizating the data probably produces the simplest data structure and queries, without imposing much overhead on maintaining the data.

EDIT:

I think your comment is describing the table with the multiple columns that I mention above.  If you want a user to select a county from such a table, then use `select distinct country_name from Places`.  If you want all the regions for a country, then user `select distinct region_name from Places where country_name = XXX`.

Comment: Thanks, maybe the best solution is to put all places in the same table, just like you said. This allows even to create more depth levels using columns like `id, name, type, id_parent`

Comment: @OscarOtero . . . I wouldn't go down the route of hierarchical structures in MySQL, because there is no support for recursive queries.  The suggestion is to flatten the structure with the hierarchy in place as separate columns -- a suggestion made because geography is a rather stable dimension.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your suggestion. Do you mean a structure like this?: `id, municipality_name, region_name, country_name` with data like: `1, 'Tordoia', 'Galicia', 'Spain'` and `2, 'O Pino', 'Galicia', 'Spain'`? I'd like to create an interface that when the user pick a country, only the regions of this country are displayed to choose and the same for the municipalities, but the user can stop in any step.